# Iterate array of embed documents to modify on MongoDB

Tags: arrays, mongodb, loops, embed

I'm trying to iterate a array of embed objects on MongoDB to modify some atributes depends of condition

I'm trying like this:

```
User.findOne({_id: id}, function (err, user) {
                if (err) {
                    return;
                }

                if (!user) {
                    return;
                }

                var documents= user.documents;
                documents.forEach(function(entry) {
                   var id = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(entry))._id;
                   var eachDocument= user.documents.id(id);
                   if(eachDocument.attribute === "string"){                            
                      eachDocument.attribute = requestToApiFunction();
                   }
                }

         user.save()
             .then(function (usuarioActualizado) {
                        return;
                    });


     });
```

Is this a correct way to do this?

Comment: What is condition ? You can use [UpdateOne](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateOne/) with your condition as filter and set value as update.

Comment: The condition is that an attribute of each document be equals to "string" if the condition is true eachDocument.otherAttribute= result of call to function. I've updated the original message

Comment: What does `callToFunction()` have ?

Comment: Request a value to restful api

Comment: Can you `callToFunction()` before you run the query ? Btw please dont update the original content the comments will lose its context.

Comment: I need to update the value of some attribute of each embed object of the array if the condition is true. Each new value of the each embed document is the result of the request to api which returns a random string id. I hope this explain more my problem

Comment: Okay if the call to rest api is necessary then I think the way you're doing is right. You can generate random value by using new ObjectID too.

Comment: The random string id is not generated by me. Is a unique id generated by an external service.

Comment: If `requestToApiFunction` is asynchronous, this won't work, the best way is to use [async.map()](http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#map)